# Am I able to do math/algebraic functions in a Text object in Crystal Reports 11

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, crystal-reports-xi

I have a crystal report v11 where I have a text object in a group footer 
{Sum of @del_ammount_over500K}/{%totalBalanceOfLoans}

the first field is a sum of a number of records in various catagories (thats what they are grouped on the second field is just the total from another column.

my challenge is I am trying to actually divide them and get a number but I get
1,000,000/5,000,000 instead of what i want .20 any ideas on how I would do that is there a EVAL() function I could wrap them in?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A text object can only contain text.  However, what you would like to do can still be accomplished within a Formula Field that performs all of the computations and outputs them as text.  Then you can place that formula field inside a text object if there is additional static text to be displayed with it.

If there is no additional static text, you can simply place the formula field on your report instead of the text object.

So in your example, if you were to create a Formula Field that has the following formula:

```
 {Sum of @del_ammount_over500K}/{%totalBalanceOfLoans}
```

You could then replace the formula in your text object with the reference to that Formula Field and it would display the result of the computation as you desire.